# Exporting array results to csv using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a powershell script utilizing the Citrix XenApp sdk. What I am trying to do is get the following values using one of the citrix cmdlets; Load, User count, and Server count (which uses another cmdlet) and export to csv.

I created a csv file that contains the name of the delivery groups I want to query, so I import that csv and start my array by calling a couple of the citrix cmdlets:

```
# Add Citrix XenApp sdk
Add-PSSnapin Citrix.*.Admin.V*
# Define Dashboard Server Name as well as import the Delivery Group csv file.
$DashboardServer = "server.name"
$delivery_group_csv = Import-Csv \\$DashboardServer\path_to_file\file.csv -Delimiter ","
# extract citrix loads per delivery group as well as Session counts for each  delivery group
foreach($silo in $delivery_group_csv) {
                            $DeliveryGroupName = $silo.DeliveryGroupName
                            $LoadIndex = Get-BrokerMachine -DesktopGroupName $DeliveryGroupName
                            $SiloLoad = ($LoadIndex | Measure-Object 'LoadIndex' -Sum).Sum/1000
                            $UserCount = ($LoadIndex | Measure-Object 'SessionCount' -Sum).Sum
                            $ServerCount = Get-BrokerDesktopGroup -Name $DeliveryGroupName
                            $DG_servercount = ($ServerCount).TotalDesktops

Write-Host $DeliveryGroupName "- Load" $SiloLoad"%" " - Servercount" $DG_servercount "- " Total Users" - " $UserCount | Export-Csv -Path \\$DashboardServer\path_to_save\new_file.csv -Append -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is when it gets exported to csv I only get a blank csv file. I am fairly new to powershell and have tried a variety of things, but completely at a loss to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Write-Host` writes output directly to the screen buffer, nothing gets piped to `Export-Csv`

Comment: makes sense. I'll keep working on it and see if I can figure out how to export the queries before the write-host line to csv.

Comment: So I removed the write-host and added the following two lines: `$Output = $DeliveryGroupName, $SiloLoad, $UserCount | Select-Object DesktopGroupName, LoadIndex, SessionCount and below that: $Output # | Export-csv \\$DashboardServer\c$\Psscripts\Dashboard\Siloload_sessionco‌​unt\loads_sessioncou‌​nts.csv -encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ","` The problem now is the headers appear but no data is appearing from the array above.